# Crear Aplicacion de C# que abra e Instale winrar.exe desde mi pendrive

Tags: c#

quiero crear una aplicacion de tipo windows form en C# que abra un .exe de asistente de instalacion y presione automaticamente los botones Siguiente> Siguiente > Finalizar (Por poner un ejemplo)

ya tengo el boton de prueba creado y tengo el codigo para abrir el .exe
mediante:
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"E:\ ..... .exe);

tambien cree una funcion  para que la aplicacion pase al frente
y le estoy pasando la tecla "Enter" varias veces para que le de al boton "siguiente " de la aplicacion pero no funciona, si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradeceria, aki les dejo mi cod hasta ahora.

//ESTE ES EL CODIGO DEL BOTON

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"E:\programas pcs\winrar-x64-411es.exe");
            Thread.Sleep(1000); 

            Funciones.ActivateApp("winrar-x64-411es.exe");

            Thread.Sleep(2000);          


            SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }

//FUNCION ACTIVATEAPP

public static void ActivateApp(string processName)
    {
        Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);       
        if (p.Count() > 0)
            SetForegroundWindow(p[0].MainWindowHandle);
    }
```

Comment: prueba ejecutando el instalador con `/S` suele ser el "Silent Switch"

Comment: no, no funciona, lo ve como parte del nombre del .exe

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"E:\programas pcs\winrar-x64-411es.exe /s"); no fuinciona ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trata usando estos parametros y metodos

```
 ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
 psi.Arguments = "/s";
 psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
 psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 psi.FileName = @"E:\programas pcs\winrar-x64-411es.exe";
 psi.UseShellExecute = false;
 Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: respuesta muy acertada, gracias